# My installation process of ViroReact gets stuck at "Loading dependency graph, done"

Tags: viro-react

I am installing ViroReact on windows from https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/quick-start-windows.

I got stuck at "Start Your Packager Server" part after executing "npm start". The installation process gets stuck at "Loading dependency graph, done." in Powershell. I am unable to view the app on my phone. Can you please advise me on how to proceed with the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **react-native run-android** in another tab.

Comment: I did open a new tab. I get the error :  Failed to load the bundle and request timed out error on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

The installation process seems to work so far and you are at the point of starting the React Native packager for test, preview etc.
After installing the ViroMedia application on your mobile, enter the Testbed. The computer and phone must be on the same WiFi network. As soon as the metro bundler runs properly (message: "Loading dependency graph, done."), provide to the Testbed your ip and you'll see in Powershell the following:

[image]

Then, you can see your app on your phone.